# How to get height of a line in UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview

[image]

As shown in above diagram ... the `lineHeight` is the height of the orange box. How can I get the height of the blue box (i.e. `lineHeight` + line spacing height)? Thanks!

UPDATE: I found the the `lineHeight` behaves differently depends on the characters in content. If the content is all in English, the lineHeight is corrent (21, for example, in the default UITextView). However, when the content is mixed with Chinese characters, the UIFont `lineHeight` is still reported as 21 while the `self.textView.contentSize.height` is increased differently:

```
English - adding 21 points for each line
Chinese - adding 24 points for each line
```

UPDATE (`sizeWithFont:`)

```
CGSize constrainedRect = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
CGSize rectEnglish = [@"hello\nworld" sizeWithFont:self.textView.font constrainedToSize:constrainedRect lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"width: %.2f height: %.2f", rectEnglish.width, rectEnglish.height);
CGSize rectChinese = [@"你\n好嗎" sizeWithFont:self.textView.font constrainedToSize:constrainedRect lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"width: %.2f height: %.2f", rectChinese.width, rectChinese.height);
```

output:

```
width: 41.00 height: 42.00
width: 34.00 height: 42.00
```

Answer (score 21):

You have to use

```
yourTextView.font.lineHeight
```

Comment: Note that `UIFont.lineHeight` is iOS4.0+ only.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`NSString` `UIKit` additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/). Some variation of `-sizeWithFont:` should be what you need.

Comment: It seems to me `-sizeWithFont` also ignore language issue (see UPDATE about `-sizeWithFont` in question)

Comment: Can’t you just use the text that will be drawn?